# by + time vs in+ time

Tags: expressions

Please, can anyone tell me about the difference between the following sentences?

> The assignment is due in two weeks from now

and

> The assignment is due by two weeks from now

Comment: There's very little difference between them: they're both wrong. it should be either: *"The assignment is due two weeks from now"* or *"The assignment is due in two weeks"*.

Comment: Use *in* not *by*. The object is a period, not a point in time. HTH.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Please cite your sources.

Comment: @Kris I do  not need to cite sources in a comment. Go troll someone else.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Making incorrect comments/ advice could be harmful to the OP.

Comment: @Kris Feel free to post a "correct" answer exposing my errors.

Comment: Also see: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/482679/at-and-by-what-are-the-differences-is-there-a-third-alternative-to-this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you would not add "from now" to the above statements because it is grammatically incorrect.  You could say

```
The assignment is due two weeks from now
```

or

```
The assignment is due by [a certain date or day of the week]
```

If you say

```
The assignment is due two weeks from now
```

this would mean that if today is January 24, 2019, then the assignment is due on February 7, 2019, which is in exactly two weeks.  It means that you (probably) wouldn't turn it in before that date.

If you say something like

```
The assignment is due by February 7, 2019
```

or

```
The assignment is due by next Thursday
```

then it implies that the assignment can be turned in any time before then.