# At and By what are the differences.Is there a third alternative to this?

Tags: prepositions, british-english

What are the differences between doing something at the end of a period and doing something by the end of a period?
For example:

I will meet her at the end of the week.
I will meet her by the end of the week.

Thanks

Comment: "At the end of the week" = at the weekend (or, if you are talking about the working week, on Friday). "By the end of the week" = at some time during the coming week.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have some work (2 days worth) to do in January, and today is the 2nd.

By **the end of the period** can be any time before the end of the period so any date before today and the 31st January

**at the end of a period** is the 30th and the 31st January

Comment: I will meet her at the end of the week. I will meet her by the end of the week.

Comment: @MehrdadY *At* means when the week is over. *By* means sometime before the week is over.